# Get img src onclick then feed it into other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a gallery set up that, upon clicking a smaller image, it will show a hidden div with a larger size with that specific image that was clicked.

I'm wondering how you set up a Jquery where, upon clicking a div, it feeds the `img src` into another `img` tag (with a variable or otherwise).

I was playing around with something like

```
function getImageSrc(x) {
   var x= document.getElementsByClassName("image").src,
   return x;
```

Which I would then feed into another function, where `x` would be the `img src` from the `getImageSrc` function, but I just can't quite wrap my head around it. I can't seem to think of how to fire an `onClick` event inside the first function without throwing in an additional function inside the first one.

Any help would be great. I'll even take a whole new direction with this if this method won't work (besides plugins).

Here is the code snippet now that I have time to get to it. I'm basically trying to pass the image src into the `.clicked` when the image is clicked, upon which the `.clicked` will go from `visibility: hidden` to `visibility: visible`.

The next script that needs to run is when the `.clicked` div is visible and clicked, it goes back to hidden.

I'm mostly having trouble figuring out the first script.

```css
.clicked {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(35,35,41,.9);
  z-index: 100;
  top:0;
  }

.imgcontainer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div class="clicked">
  <img class="clickedimg" src="">
 </div>

<div class="imgcontainer">
  <img class="image" src="https://processing.org/tutorials/pixels/imgs/tint1.jpg">
 </div>
```

Comment: Post the HTML structure

Comment: Can you show your code snippet that you are working on?

Comment: show us your mark up mate

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple, Code explains itself

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.small > img').click(function() {
    $('.big > img').prop('src', $(this).prop('src'));
    $('.big').show();
  })
});
```

```css
.small {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.small >img,
.big > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.big {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small">
  <img src="https://processing.org/tutorials/pixels/imgs/tint1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="big">
  <img />
</div>
```

Comment: I thought this would work by simply switching around some of the calls in the script, but it unfortunately seems to do nothing upon clicking an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
function getImageSrc(x){
    var x= document.getElementsByClassName("image").src;
    //Call the function to append the img src to the new element
    appendImageSrc(x);
}

function appendImageSrc(imageSrc){
    //append the src to the new Element
    document.getElementsByClassName("imageLarger").src = imageSrc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#open_page").click(function(){

        var go_to_url = $("#redirect").find(":selected").val();
        document.location.href = go_to_url;
    });
});
```

You could do something like this

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. I think this will help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("SmallerImageURL").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_(JPEG-HDR).jpg";
        });

        function EnlargeImage() {
            var SmallImg = getImageSrc("SmallerImageURL");
            document.getElementById("EnlargedImageURL").src = SmallImg;
        }

        function getImageSrc(ImageClass) {
            var x = $("."+ImageClass).attr("src");
            return x;
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .SmallContainer {
            width: 250px;
            float: left;
        }
        
        .LargeContainer {
            width: 500px;
            float: left;
        }
        
        .LargeContainer img,
        .SmallContainer img {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .row {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="SmallContainer">
        <img id="SmallerImageURL" class="SmallerImageURL"/>
    </div>
    <div class="LargeContainer">
        <img id="EnlargedImageURL" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button onclick="EnlargeImage()">Enlarge Me</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have made a small modification to your `getImageSrc` method. I think implementing the same in jQuery is much better.